# Could not find dependency "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0"

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle

I created a google map project by default in Android studio.
 when gradle syncing after CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL message this error appear:

ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0
Install Repository and sync project
....

When i clicked on Install Repository ... this message appear:

Could not find dependency "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0".

How can i install that without this prompt error window?

Comment: Add apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' to your gradle file

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin it seems a solution but you know it was created based on Android studio default. It doesn't work.

Comment: My comment works?

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin Unfortunately no! :(

Comment: What about the link which your question is linked to?

Comment: @MohammadMoeinGolchin The main problem is that Gradle doesn't build. Other  problem with this derivative is that it is not installed.

Comment: file->inavlidate caches/restart

Comment: After much effort, I was able to solve the problem. Strange as it may seem, the problem was solved by manually adjusting the proxy.

thanks all.

Comment: I couldn't suggest you to use VPN here :)